# Adding icon to Extjs toolbar

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4.2

I am trying to add an icon to my toolbar (arbitrary - not associated with a button).

In my CSS I define the URL like this :

```
.myCoolLookingIcon {
    background-image: url('../ext-theme-gray/images/grid/columns.gif');
}
```

And that works fine if I am setting icons for buttons by using **iconCls**.

I would like this icon in a label or image

I have tried :

```
            xtype: 'label',
            iconCls: 'myCoolLookingIcon '
```

and

```
            xtype: 'image',
            html: '<img class="myCoolLookingIcon "/>'
```

but that doesn't seem to work in either case.

Comment: You can't just make up configs. Label doesn't have an `iconCls` config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the way of achieving what you want (Not using the iconCls)

```
xtype:'label',
html: '<img src=\"path_to_icon\">'
```

Try this:

```
 xtype:'label',
 html: '<img class="className" width="20" height="20">'
```

Giving width and height, makes it work.

Comment: yeah i looked at that. Just seems a bit too messy for me

Comment: ahh forgot the width and height in my example :) thanks

Comment: The second suggestion creates a grey border because no src is specified.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately I ended up doing this.  A little hacky but it worked.

```
{
    xtype: 'label',
    itemId: 'labelWithIcon',
    text: '',
    cls: 'classNameWithImgBackground',
    listeners: {
      render: function () {
        this.setText('<span style="margin-left: 16px;">Label Text</span>', false);
      }
    }
}
```